# If I already have Angular 17 installed, why is it only compatible with Angular 16?

Tags: angular

This is the terminal output. Let me know if `package.json` is needed.

In my `package.json`, I have set the dependency to >=17.0.0

```
(base) shravya@Shravyas-MBP Remit2AnyAdminWebapp % ng serve
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^16.0.0,
but Angular version 17.0.9 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/

(base) shravya@Shravyas-MBP Remit2AnyAdminWebapp % ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 17.0.7
Node: 20.10.0
Package Manager: npm 10.2.5
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: <error>
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... material, material-luxon-adapter, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
    
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.7 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            17.0.7 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.7 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    17.0.7 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             17.0.7 (cli-only)
rxjs                            7.8.1 (cli-only)
typescript                      <error>
zone.js                         <error>
```

I also don't know why typescript says error. Is it because I didn't explicitly install it? Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running the `ng` globally, so it will take the version of Angular that is installed globally. Please install the latest version of Angular cli globally using the below command

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@17.0.7
```

Optionally you can install Angular core also!

```
npm i -g @angular/core@17.0.7
```

---

Please try clearing the cache using `npm cache clean --force` delete the `node_modules` and `package.json` and try to reinstall to see if it works!

---

If you do not want to install, you can run `npx ng serve` to run the local version of Angular cli, that may solve your issue.

Comment: makes sense but in my package.json, I set angular version to >=17.0.0 and 17.0.9 was installed when I did npm install

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu We also have angular install globally sometimes, and depending upon the location, the global version might be taken into account and might cause your issue!

Comment: global version is 17.0.7 and package dependency version of angular is 17.0.9

Comment: is it possible that I didn't update properly?